# simulating web app in window form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, window

how to make 5 request to url  https://www.example.co.in/test/CheckOpening.jsf  using webclient in interval of 1 second without waiting 1st response. following are code where i am making 1 request. i need to make 5 same request at 1 second interval.

```
**

    ajaxCall:
        string sold = webClient.AjaxPost("https://www.example.co.in/test/CheckOpening.jsf", sPostData);
        if (!sold.Contains("Start Now"))
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(0, "not open so hiting ajax again.");
            goto ajaxCall;
        }

**
```

Comment: Why not use Windows Task Scheduler to start your app at 9:59:30? If you want help writing your code in parallel, then you'll need to share the code that works in synch and we'll help you thread it.

Comment: i need help in making 5 parellel post request using webclient and after need to check if any respond with "Start now"

Comment: string sold = webClient.AjaxPost("https://www.example.co.in/test/CheckOpening.jsf sPostData); this is what i do